# How to install python packages from more than pypi repository?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, pipenv

I'm using `pipenv` as package management tool and for my project I use packages from pypi and other private local project for that we did a private pypi repo, but when trying to install the packages, I got the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/8.3.2_1/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 382, in prepare_pip_source_args
    pip_args.extend(['-i', sources[0]['url']])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

My Pipfile looks as follow:

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[[source]]
url = "https://my.domain.com/repository/"
verify_ssl = true
name = "local"

[packages]

flask = "*"
sqlalchemy = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
...
my_project = {version="*", index="local"}


[dev-packages]

tox = "*"
pytest = "*"
"flake8" = "*"


[requires]

python_version = "3.6"
```

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix the issue!?

Comment: Did you try with the latest version of pipenv ?

Comment: It's version: `8.3.2`